# How to install libc++ on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) in Travis?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, travis-ci, libc++

In the [Travis Ubuntu-precise apt whitelist](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-precise) there is the package libc++-dev listed, which I try to install via

```
# .travis.yml
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    - kubuntu-backports
    - llvm-toolchain-precise
    packages:
    - g++-4.8
    - cmake
    - libc++-dev
```

What happens in the APT step in the Travis job is

```
$ sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install g++-4.8 cmake libc++-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
libc-dev-bin is already the newest version.
libc-dev-bin set to manually installed.
libc6-dev is already the newest version.
libc6-dev set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxmlrpc-core-c3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cmake-data cpp-4.8 emacsen-common gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-6-base libasan0
  libatomic1 libc6-armel-cross libc6-armhf-cross libcloog-isl4 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgcc1 libgcc1-armel-cross libgcc1-armhf-cross libgomp1 libisl10 libitm1
  libpurelibc1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0
Suggested packages:
  codeblocks eclipse gcc-4.8-locales dietlibc-doc g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc
  libstdc++6-4.8-dbg gcc-4.8-multilib libmudflap0-4.8-dev libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libbacktrace1-dbg libquadmath0-dbg libmudflap0-dbg binutils-gold
  libstdc++-4.8-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.8 dietlibc-dev g++-4.8 gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base gcc-6-base libasan0
  libatomic1 libc6-armel-cross libc6-armhf-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
  libc6-dev-armhf-cross libcloog-isl4 libgcc-4.8-dev libgcc1-armel-cross
  libgcc1-armhf-cross libisl10 libitm1 libklibc-dev libowfat-dietlibc-dev
  libpurelibc-dev libpurelibc1 libstdc++-4.8-dev libtsan0
  linux-libc-dev-armel-cross linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cmake cmake-data emacsen-common libgcc1 libgomp1 libquadmath0 libstdc++6
  linux-libc-dev
8 upgraded, 26 newly installed, 0 to remove and 242 not upgraded.
Need to get 43.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

So you can see that libc++-dev is not mentioned anymore after the install command line. What happens is that the following packages are added:

- libc-dev-bin
- libc6-dev
- libc6-armel-cross
- libc6-armhf-cross
- libgcc1-armel-cross
- libgcc1-armhf-cross
- libpurelibc1

so I guess there is some regular expression magic going on (does libc++-dev match libc6-dev?).

So, how do I install libc++-dev on Travis?

Comment: Have you tried *using* it first? Package managers is as package managers do and it might work

Comment: I tried to use libc++ but it is not available

Comment: Alright, now it gets interesting. You looked through the bugtracker? Do so and open an issue there if none exists already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that the repositories listed under `sources` don't provide libc++-dev, so you can't install the package (at least not from these repositories).

When a package doesn't exist, apt-get and apt (not aptitude) fall back to interpreting the name as a regular expression that matches all packages that contain the regex. If you don't like this, you could formulate the package name as a regex: `^libc\+\+-dev$`